# How to abbreviate a multiple background css rule?

Tags: css, background-image

Hi,

I have this CSS code:

```
.point1 {background:url(../images/top/pointback.png) no-repeat 0 110px / 100% 35%,url(../images/top/point1back.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 / 100%;}
.point2 {background:url(../images/top/pointback.png) no-repeat 0 110px / 100% 35%,url(../images/top/point2back.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 / 100%;}
.point3 {background:url(../images/top/pointback.png) no-repeat 0 110px / 100% 35%,url(../images/top/point3back.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 / 100%;}
.point4 {background:url(../images/top/pointback.png) no-repeat 0 110px / 100% 35%,url(../images/top/point4back.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 / 100%;}
```

as you may see, all 4 rules are almost identical except for the second background image which changes for each case. I wonder whether is possible to simplify that so I can declare everything with a single rule. Something like this:

```
.point1, point2, point3, point4 {background:url(../images/top/pointback.png) no-repeat 0 110px / 100% 35%}

.point1 {url(../images/top/point1back.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 / 100%;}
.point2 {url(../images/top/point2back.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 / 100%;}
.point3 {url(../images/top/point3back.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 / 100%;}
.point4 {url(../images/top/point4back.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 / 100%;}
```

Thank you.

Comment: It seems that your are looking for SASS or LESS variables.

Comment: Sorry, never heard of those.

Comment: Here's a tutorial for sass https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-sass

Comment: Thank you but it means I have to install external libraries or something like that? I would prefer a pure CSS solution without externals.

Comment: can't be done with just CSS

Comment: Well it can...just not exactly as might be required.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done but it's probably not the completely *terse* solution you are looking for

You can declare the properties as all the same as the first declaration and then **override** the specific `background-image` property/value to be used in each class.

Unfortunately, there is no method to do this *just* for the second background image or combine this into a single property.

```
.point1,
.point2,
.point3,
.point4{
  background: url(../images/top/pointback.png) no-repeat 0 110px / 100% 35%, url(../images/top/point1back.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 / 100%;
}

.point2 {
  background-image: url(../images/top/pointback.png), url(../images/top/point2back.jpg);
}

.point3 {
  background-image: url(../images/top/pointback.png), url(../images/top/point3back.jpg);
}

.point4 {
  background-image: url(../images/top/pointback.png), url(../images/top/point4back.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Its okay. If this is the minimal expression its fine with me. I just want to save as much code as possible.